# When using the built-in Zoom windows sdk, Zoom icons are incorrectly displayed only in the release and profile builds

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows, flutter-build

I am using embedded Zoom windows sdk in Flutter application. But in release and profile builds Zoom icons are incorrectly displayed. Everything is normal in the debug build.
Any ideas, what are the differences in flutter windows configuration for release and debug that can cause this behavior?

What I see in the debug build on Windows (correct):

[image]
[image]

What I see in the release build on Windows (incorrect):

[image]
[image]

On mouseover, Zoom icons appear while the cursor is on them, but this doesn't work for all of them.

My work with Zoom windows sdk is organized like this:

1. A flutter plugin project was created to work with Zoom sdk (https://github.com/veselv2010/flutter_zoom_sdk/tree/master).
2. This plugin is used in another project.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?